# Subjunctive mood sentence about busyness setting up a question

Tags: subjunctives, tense-agreement

Which sentence from the following is correct?

> Suppose you ***were*** very busy last night. Would you have watched this film?

OR

> Suppose you ***had been*** very busy last night. Would you have watched this film?

Answer (score 2):

Tense-shifting to mark hypotheticals is disappearing from the language, so either form of the question would be acceptable;  *had been* more clearly marks the hypothetical as a past hypothetical, corroborating "last night".